# async parallel Limit crashing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing

I am trying to use async parallel limit  but every time I use it  it seems to just stop.
and not continue after the first iteration. I want it to continue until the array is finished How do I do this?

```
const parallelLimit = require("async/parallelLimit");
async function publishMessage(data) {
  const messageId = await pubSubClient
    .topic(topicName)
    .publishJSON(data)
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  console.log(messageId);
}
messages = messages.flat();
        let promises = messages.map((row) => {
          return () => publishMessage(row);
        });
        
        await parallelLimit(promises, 4000);
```

Comment: what is `publishMessage`?

Comment: doesn't return function have a callback param ? I guess you should call when your async computation is completed.

Comment: added the publishmessage @ikhvjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a array of async functions to parallelLimit().

```js
const parallelLimit = require("async/parallelLimit");

function publishMessage(data) {
  return async function () {
    try {
      const messageId = await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publishJSON(data);
      console.log(messageId);
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  };
}

const asyncFuncs = messages.flat().map(row => publishMessage(row));

(async function run() {
  try {
    await parallelLimit(asyncFuncs, 4000);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I just used your code and I get this error 
Error: expected a function
    at wrapAsync (/node_modules/async/internal/wrapAsync.js:27:46)
Also I already am inserting an array of async functions

Comment: @Oas, your approach is only passing a sync function, but not an async funciton. From you error message, did you copy my codes of the `publishMessage()`? please show me your codes in some fiddle if possible.

Comment: ahh okay I made a mistake when I copying your code it  i left it as an async function   I unwrapped the parallel limit and now it works fine. thanks. for your help